# Will this ChildWindow be collected by GC?

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection

Recently I have been using anonymous method a lot, so I wonder if I do like:

Say in my MainWindow class, I have:

```
ChildWindow myChildWindow = new ChildWindow();
myChildWindow.Closing+= (o, e) => {
 //DoSomething
 rootGrid.Children.Remove(o as ChildWindow);
}
this.rootGrid.Children.Add(myChildWindow );
myChildWindow.Show();
```

In this case I won't be able to remove the event handler from `.Closing` since is defined with anonymous method.

Will this ChildWindow still be collected by GC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

All you're doing is creating a delegate with closure object and referencing that from the child window.

You aren't creating any additional references *to* the child window.

Comment: Do you mean the closure object  is an object that defiend in ChildWindow class? like `public ClosingHandler Closing`?  So additional references will be if my MainWindow class still have an object reference to the ChildWindow `ChildWindow anotherReferece = myChildWindow`, in that case it won't collected by GC?

Comment: See [my blog post](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-4-c.html) for more on closures.  You don't need to worry about the GC here.